# Spring security auto redirect to login page after session timeout

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, timeout

I need to redirect automatically to login page after session timeout or at least show alert that session is expired, I tried to configure Spring Security, but it is not working ,debugger don't catch code in LogoutSuccessHandlerService after timeout. Maybe I missed something or this approach with Spring Security is wrong from the start?
If it is so, can somebody provide full working example of such task? I am using Spring Boot 2.5.6, Spring Security, front-end is html, javascript, JQuery and dataTable.
Here is my code:

SecurityConfig.java

```
private final AppProperties appProperties;

@Autowired
private LogoutSuccessHandlerService logoutSuccessHandlerService;

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/static/**")
            .antMatchers("/webjars/**")
            .antMatchers("/css/**")
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**")
            .antMatchers("/img/**")
            .antMatchers("/js/**")
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
    ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandlerService)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    AppProperties.Security security = appProperties.getSecurity();

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(security.getUser())
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode(security.getPassword()))
            .roles(security.getRole());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

LogoutSuccessHandlerService.java extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler

```
@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication != null) {

    }
    log.info("logout success");
    setDefaultTargetUrl("/login");
    
    super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

application-local.yml

server:
port: 8086
servlet:
session:
timeout: 2m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Spring security is unable to solve it, I used JavaScript. This solution sends request every minute and if response data is not null, redirect occurs. It works only with one logged in user in browser.

Header html page

```
<script>
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/check-session",
                    method: "GET",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function(data){
                        if (data && data.length > 0) {
                            window.location.replace("/login");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log("error");
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })
            }, 60000);
    </script>
```

LoginController

```
@GetMapping("/check-session")
public ResponseEntity<String> checkSession() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I tried to implement this js, if i set interval lower than my session timeout, it results in my session never expires. In my case my session timeout might vary, so I need to set a variable value for interval

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
   var sessionExpiresIn = [[${sessionExpiresIn}]];
   if (sessionExpiresIn === null || sessionExpiresIn === undefined) {
       sessionExpiresIn = 1799; // Default value
   } else {
       sessionExpiresIn = parseInt(sessionExpiresIn) + 1;
    }
</script>
```

If I didnt set default value it will results in infinite loop of check-session api calls